# Downloading embedded Iframe videos from vimeo using python

Tags: javascript, python, video, download, vimeo

I have been looking all over and I see how to download vimeo videos using python. I so far have this code.I can get to the parent page but I cannot do anything to hit that iframe. I was thinking the best way to do this would be login and hit the iframe and download the video from there but I am missing something. do any of you have any ideas?
let me know if you need more info and as always thank you for your time.

```
import spynner
import os, sys, urllib

os.system("dir")

browser = spynner.Browser()
#browser.show()
url = 'https://somelink.php'
browser.load("https://somelink2.php")
browser.wk_fill("input[name=log]", "loginname")
browser.wk_fill("input[name=pwd]", "password")
browser.click("#wp-submit")
print browser.url, len(browser.html)
browser.load("http://somelink3-00000333/")
browser.click("//player.vimeo.com/video/747474749")
print browser.html
```

Here is the embedded video that I would like to download.

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/747474749" width="500" height="281"
frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Site allowed for Javascript to be run from the client side.
so in short a simply running javascript to access the link is enough.
javascript:window.location.href="%s"; '%uls  is really all that was needed to have this happen. I hope it helps others in the future and perhaps there is a better way to do this please let me know.

```
def getvideourl(htmldoc): 
        downloadurls = re.findall("//player.+video.\d+", htmldoc) 
        for uls in downloadurls: 
            uls.encode('ascii','ignore') 
            javasinject = 'javascript:window.location.href="%s"; '%uls 
            return javasinject 

    def jsinject(link): 
        str(link) 
        browser.runjs(link) 


    jsinject(str(getvideourl(browser.html))) 
    browser._wait_load()
```